# Loading a menu from menu.html with JQuery, then making the current link active

Tags: jquery, html

Attempting to add 'active' class to the link that corresponds with the current page, on a menu that is stored in menu.html, and pulled through to index.html with JQuery.

I've managed to call my menu.html file with JQuery and insert the menu into index.html. The CSS styling all pulls through perfectly. However, as I'm now not adding the 'active' class to each menu item individually, I need a method of doing this. I've managed to add an active class to the menu when it was all under one roof in index.html, but not now I've moved it out into its own separate file. I've got the point of being able to either have the links working, or have 'active' added which is shown below.

menu.html:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(function() {
    $('.side a').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="side">
  <a href="/intro.html">Intro</a>
  <a href="/contact.html">Contact</a>
  <a href="/about.html">About</a>
</div>
```

I'd expect the above to show my menu, show the active link, and then for the links to take the user to each different page. The menu is show, it does show the active link, but the links do not work now.

Comment: so you are trying to route to different html pages. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I use:  <script> 
  $(function(){
    $("#footer_nav").load("/footer.html"); 
    $("#side_menu_nav").load("/menu.html"); 
  });
 </script>  in the head. And  <div id="side_menu_nav"></div> in the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare a url variable to see which is the current page then add the active class to it:

```
<script>
    // This line will give you the active page without parameters
    var url = window.location.href.split('/')[window.location.href.split('/').length-1].split('?')[0];
    $('a[href$="'+url+'"]').addClass('active');
</script>
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much! I'd be trying to get this working for so long. I've placed this script in my menu.html and it works perfectly.